# Asp.Net Core migration path error

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create a DB from EF Core migration. 
With this connection string.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=BookList_RazorDemo;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

}

The add-migration command on the PMC works fine, but when I execute update-database it give me an error saying that it cannot open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\[User]BookList_RazorDemo.mdf', the users name and the mdf file name are not separated by .

Is there a parameter I can specify with the update-database command to set my output path for the mdf file, or where can I set the output directory otherwise?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path to your .mdf file by adding `AttachDbFileName` to the connection string ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017#connecting-to-the-automatic-instance)):

`Server=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=D:\Data\MyDB1.mdf`

Comment: Nice, it works. Last time I was using EF Core it didn't recognise AttachDbFIleName as property.

Answer (score 0):

This is Fixed in latest SQL Server 2017 CU!

https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/384#issuecomment-398313650